# Issue Combining Worksheet_Change subs (Invalid or Unqualified Reference Error)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project that uses a `Worksheet_Change` sub to make certain images visible or invisible based on the value of a particular cell (in this case `B23`).

Now I'm trying to add a second criteria to make a different set of images visible/invisible based on the value in a different cell (in this case `B24`).

The problem is that I'm now getting a `"Invalid or Unqualified Reference"` Error, and it looks like it has to do with the `".pictures"` piece. Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$B$23,$B$24")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address = "$B$23" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "driving"
                .Pictures("Auto_Map_Labeled").Visible = True
                .Pictures("Bicycle_Map_Labeled").Visible = False
                .Pictures("Pedestrian_Map_Labeled").Visible = False
            Case "bicycling"
                .Pictures("Auto_Map_Labeled").Visible = False
                .Pictures("Bicycle_Map_Labeled").Visible = True
                .Pictures("Pedestrian_Map_Labeled").Visible = False
            Case "walking"
                .Pictures("Auto_Map_Labeled").Visible = False
                .Pictures("Bicycle_Map_Labeled").Visible = False
                .Pictures("Pedestrian_Map_Labeled").Visible = True
        End Select

    ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$24" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "visible"
                .Pictures("Thumbs_Up").Visible = True
            Case "invisible"
                .Pictures("Thumbs_Up").Visible = False
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong? I should note that I'm very new to VBA, so looking for the simplest solution possible.

Comment: Add `With Me` after `If Target.Address = "$B$23` and `End With` before `End Sub`. That qualifies the `.Pictures` lines, so that they're equivalent to `Me.Pictures...`.